# Why my object still gets copied when I tried to return a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, auto, lvalue

```
class Obj {
public:
    Obj(int aa, int bb): a(aa), b(bb) {}
    Obj(const Obj& o) {a = o.a; b = o.b;std::cout << "copying" << std::endl;}
    Obj(Obj&& o) {a = o.a; b = o.b;std::cout << "moving" << std::endl;}
    int a;
    int b;
};
const Obj& Min(const Obj &o1, const Obj &o2) {
    if (o1.a > o2.a) {
        return o1;
    } else {
        return o2;
    }
}
int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto o1 = Obj(1,1);
    auto o2 = Obj(2,2);
    auto res = Min(o1, o2);

    cout << res.a << endl;
    res.a = 100;
    cout << o1.a << endl;
    cout << o2.a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program still prints a word `copying` which indicates that the copy constructor is activated. Where is the constructor called then ? Why the function does not return a reference of `o1` so that modifying the value of `res` will also changing the value of `o1` ?

Comment: Try `auto& res = Min(o1, o2)`, but don't expect `res.a = 100` to work then, since you're returning `const` reference.

Comment: So this means that construction is implemented at assigning the left reference returned by ```Min``` to a non-reference variable ```res``` ? What if I need to use ```auto&& res = Min(...)``` to capture the value, how could I make this work ?

Comment: Anyway, returning a **`const`** reference will prevent the modification of `o1`.

Comment: See also `decltype(auto)`, which neither of the answers here mention; that can net a reference without having to write one, so it's better if you were writing code that had to be generic. @coincheung What do you mean "What if"? You just wrote it. But is there a reason you need an rvalue reference there? You'll still get a `const` reference if you are returning a reference to a member of a `const` object. All the generic code in the world can't bypass that, and rightly.

Answer (score 8):

The copy is done in the statement:

```
auto res = Min(o1, o2);
```

`Min()` return type is `const Obj&`. The `auto` above will be deduced to `Obj`, not `const Obj&` (i.e., `res` type will be `Obj`). `res`, which is an object, is initialized by means of the copy constructor (i.e., `Obj::Obj(const Obj&)`), therefore a copy construction takes place.

If you write instead:

```
auto& res = Min(o1, o2)
```

`res` will be of type `const Obj&` and no copy construction takes place there, since `res` will be a reference, not an object.

Comment: bonus points if you reference the part of the std that requires this.

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with how `auto` deduces the type:

From the CPP working draft (N4713):

> **10.1.7.4.1 Placeholder type deduction [dcl.type.auto.deduct]**
>   ...
>   4. If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type T' replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

And:

> **17.9.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call [temp.deduct.call]**
>   ...
>   2. If P is not a reference type:
>   ...
>     (2.3) — If A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of A’s type are   ignored for type deduction.
>
> 3. If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

So the auto in the below statement

```
auto res = Min(o1, o2);
```

deduces `res` as `Obj` thus invoking the copy-constructor at the assignment.

So modifying the above to this:

```
auto& res = Min(o1, o2);
```

will enable `auto` to deduce `res` as `const Obj&`.

But if you do this, `res` cannot be modified in main as it is a `const` reference